# Subplot problems

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

Whenever, I try to use subplot sometimes it works other times not really it print out the figure without the graph on it:

```
plt.subplot(3,2,1)

sns.lmplot(x = 'SalePrice', y = 'GrLivArea', data = df1)

plt.subplot(3,2,2)

sns.lmplot(x = 'SalePrice', y = 'GarageCars', data = df1)

plt.subplot(3,2,3)

sns.lmplot(x = 'SalePrice', y = 'GarageArea', data = df1)

plt.subplot(3,2,4)

sns.lmplot(x = 'SalePrice', y = 'TotalBsmtSF', data = df1)

plt.subplot(3,2,5)

sns.lmplot(x = 'SalePrice', y = '1stFlrSF', data = df1)

plt.subplot(3,2,6)

sns.lmplot(x = 'SalePrice', y = 'FullBath', data = df1)
```

The output of the above code creates 6 different figures with only the last figure showing the lmplot. I am using Spyder if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you have called the constructed of `plt.subplot` 6 times which created 6 canvas, and only the last one was plotted on the last canvas given how you constructed the code. More detail on how the constructor works here[`plt.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html), the 3rd option which you feed in constructer makes `sharex` option `True` rather than specify where the figure goes.

There is sample code below, and it should achieve what you desire. You can always loop over index and iterate over the columns to make the code more presentable.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplot(3,2)

sns.lmplot(x = 'SalePrice', y = 'GrLivArea', data = df1, ax = axes[0, 0])

sns.lmplot(x = 'SalePrice', y = 'GarageCars', data = df1, ax = axes[0, 1])

sns.lmplot(x = 'SalePrice', y = 'GarageArea', data = df1, ax = axes[1, 0])

sns.lmplot(x = 'SalePrice', y = 'TotalBsmtSF', data = df1, ax = axes[1, 1])

sns.lmplot(x = 'SalePrice', y = '1stFlrSF', data = df1, ax = axes[2, 0])

sns.lmplot(x = 'SalePrice', y = 'FullBath', data = df1, ax = axes[2, 1])

plt.show()
```

Let me know if it works!